# Best way to open an URL in Vim

Tags: command-line, file, vim

Lets say that you have either URL or a link on a webpage that is a text file.  How would be the easiest way for the user to be able to open that file in a Vim?

- Right click and save link as?
- Use a specific file extension that defaults to Vim?
- Command line command?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Depending on how your vim binary was built you can just give vim the url:

`vim http://www.google.com/`

Vim spawns curl and grabs the file, then opens it.

Comment: As of Vim 7.4, neither of the above works.  You need to say:
:e http://google.com/  The protocol and trailing slash all matter.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to just open a link in vim, how about this:

```
curl http://www.google.com | vim -
```

*EDIT*
to make this command easier you can always user your browser of choice's "Copy link address" option.

*EDIT*
Given @speshak's answer and my own, I would say the "easiest" way would be option 3, "a command line command".

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: use command

```
" gvimrc

for g:chrome_exe in [
    \'C:\...\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
    \]
    if !filereadable(g:chrome_exe)
        continue
    endif
    command -nargs=+ URL :exe "silent !start ".g:chrome_exe." <args>"
    break
endfor
```

Now when you type: `:URL https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en`
it will open [google news](https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en)

---

## Solution 2: use function

or if you have a file that records a lot of URLs, and you want to use hotkey to open it, then you can try in this way

```
" .gvimrc
let g:chrome_exe = 'C:/.../Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'

function OpenURL()
    normal "*yy
    " let result = getreg("x")
    " return result
    :execute "silent !start ".g:chrome_exe2." ".getreg("*")
endfunction

map ,url :call OpenURL()<CR>
```

and then, you can open it with `,url`

```
" test.txt
https://www.google.com/
https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en
```

## Explanation of command

*URL* is a name, choose by you. (remember User-defined commands must start with an **uppercase** letter)

### what is the [command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2)

```
command -nargs=+ Say :echo "<args>"
```

Now when you type `:Say Hello World`

Vim echoes "Hello World".

### nargs

- -nargs=0  No arguments
- -nargs=1  One argument
- -nargs=*  Any number of arguments
- -nargs=?  Zero or one argument
- -nargs=+  One or more arguments

Answer (score -5):

I have used `links` before since RedHat days. The command would be

`links http://www.google.com`

If `links` is not installed, you can do `sudo apt-get install links` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to install it.

Hope it helps.